# Change webpackMode depending on some condition

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I got a project using `webpack@4` I am currently importing a 3rd party library in a lazy manner. My import looks like that:

```
const externalLibrary = await import(/* webpackMode: "lazy" */ 'external-library');
```

However I stumbed across a problem where sometimes I need the library to be imported in an eager way. Is there a way to conditionally switch between "eager" and "lazy". Something like this:

```
const externalLibrary = await import(/* webpackMode: process.env.NODE_ENV == "production" ? "lazy" : "eager" */ 'external-library');
```

Is there a way to do it?

I found an open issue on github: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5029 that has the same problem.